# how to send data from one ViewController to another which has SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have impleented SWRevealViewController for sideMenu. My project is is Swift and SWRevealViewController is in Objective-c. SWRevealViewController is not initial view Controller.there is one intial View Contoller(1VC) and it has Push segue on SWRevealViewController. another ViewController (2VC) is act as FrontView. I want to pass data from (1VC) to (2VC). but I could not find any way

[image]
    [image: Here is My Stroyboard]

Comment: what kind of data you want to send?

Comment: some String From Intial ViewController(which is before SWRevealViewController) to anotherViewController (here is DashBoard which is SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController segue)

Comment: In this kind of situation the NSNotificationCenter is best way to complete the functionality. For more reference please see https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/03/nsnotification-nsnotificationcenter-in.html

Comment: In swift everything is public, so you can define your variables outside the scope of class i.e. after import statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

In case of segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!,sender: AnyObject!){         
//make sure that the segue is going to secondViewController
if segue.destinationViewController is secondViewController{
// now set a var that points to that new viewcontroller so you can call the method correctly
let nextController = (segue.destinationViewController as! secondViewController)
nextController.setResultLabel((String(myResult)))
 }
}
```

Otherwise in swift everything is public by default. Define variables outside the class

```
import UIKit

var placesArray: NSMutableArray!

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
//
..
//
}
```

and then access it

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
//
placesArray = [1, 2, 3]
//
```

}

Comment: Pleasure is all mine